# require request map url for all

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using the grails spring-security-core plugin with a db requestmap. I was wondering if there was a configuration option that would allow me to lock all pages that do not have a configured url and role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true` in `Config.groovy` - see "Pessimistic Lockdown" in section 5 of [the docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/).

Comment: Thanks Burt! I was hoping you would answer!  Surprised i missed this in the docs.  Must of been too much x-mas egg-nog ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about locking them completely, but you could possibly restrict them to an admin role (or some dummy role that no users have).  You'd need to be able to come up with an applicable wildcard for those pages to represent in Requestmap.url.